# Filtering out unwanted data from ping return

Tags: python, python-3.x, ping

I am trying to ping the Google DNS to get the latency of the internet connection to be then sent down a COM port into a arduino with fancy lights and a few gimmicks so I don't have to alt tab into the CMD prompt every few minutes. Issue been the code below either doesn't filter out the needed information or plain up refuses to work, without me knowing a lot about programming it has become quite the challenge.

```
import subprocess
import re

ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "8.8.8.8", "-n", "1"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output = ping.communicate()

pattern = r"time= (\d+\S+)"
re.findall(pattern, output[0].decode('utf-8'))[0]
print(output)
```

The output is:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

However if I change

```
pattern = r"time= \d+\S+)"
```

to

```
pattern = r"Average = \d+\S+)"
```

the output becomes:

```
(b'\r\nPinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:\r\nReply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=122\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 8.8.8.8:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),\r\nApproximate round trip times in milli-seconds:\r\n    Minimum = 26ms, Maximum = 26ms, Average = 26ms\r\n', b'')
```

It pings the Google DNS but doesn't filter out the 20ms that is the needed part, ideally would have the output as 20 without the ms.

Any ideas where my little head has gone wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: In addition to my answer, I'd like to know whether if your pattern is meant to be `time= \d+\S+)` or `time= (\d+\S+)`. If so that's a syntax error.

Comment: I've plugged in your answer and it works, and yeah I've realised that in the code few different places where the ( was... (\d+\S+).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something like the following could help you:

```py
import re

m = re.search(r'time=(\d+)ms', output[0].decode('utf-8'))
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Additionally, you might want to cast your result to an `int`, i.e.

```py
if m:
    latency = int(m.group(1))
```

(that won't change the output, but now your manipulating a number, not a string anymore).

The problem was the space character () before the equal one `=`. Since there are none in the string you provided, you regex failed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex pattern to `r'\btime=\s*(\d+)'`